# sapply equivalent in python?

Tags: python, r, sapply

I need to grow a python DataFrame one row at a time.

In R, the `sapply()` function is fast & efficent. E.g.,

```
sapply(1:100, function(i) rnorm(50) )
```

produces a 50 x 100 matrix of (standard normal random) numbers, which can then be transposed and/or converted into a data frame, as needed

How to do same efficiently in python?

Comment: You can't just use a `for` loop?  That's pretty much what `sapply()` is under the hood.

Comment: Actually, it's more efficient to do `matrix(rnorm(5000), nrow = 50)`...

Comment: And even within `sapply`, it's more efficient to do `sapply(integer(100), function(i) rnorm(50))` (what `replicate` does). Most efficient I can see is `structure(rnorm(5000), .Dim = c(50L, 100L))`.

Answer (score 7):

`sapply` in R is equivalent to `map` in python.

`sapply(c(-1, 1), abs)` in R is equivalent to `map(abs, (-1, 1))` in Python. But `map` returns a map object, so you need to pass it to `list()` if you want a list. In Python, you can also use list comprehension `[abs(i) for i in (-1, 1)]`.

Your example is not a good use case of `sapply`. The matrix can be achieved without using it: `matrix(rnorm(5000), 50, 100)`. Equivalently, in Python, with `import numpy as np`, this can be achieved with `np.random.normal(size=(50, 100))`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following list comprehension version:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.randn(50) for i in range(100)])
```

Answer (score 0):

While list comprehensions are the more general alternative to `sapply()`, for the stated problem the most efficient method is to omit the list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# randn takes dimensions for args: randn(d1, d2, ..., dn)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50,100))
```

Answer (score -1):

Python can easily accomplish such thing through list comprehension:

```
import random as rand
[[rand.gauss(mu=0, sigma=1) for column in range(50)] for row in range(100)]
```

Otherwise, you can then use the `NumPy` package to do advanced matrix operations.

--Andrea